# How's this stackexchange doing in terms of usage and audience?

Tags: discussion

Aside from the more detailed [self-evaluations](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381/philosophy-self-evaluation-how-are-you-doing), there are some interesting stats on the usage of philo.sx out there. Here's the [**Qantcast data**](http://www.quantcast.com/philosophy.stackexchange.com) about philosophy.stackexchange.com.

Please note:

- It seems that mods have access to this kind of informations. It's nice to have this kind of information available for all users.
- These stats are not just estimates, but [display reliable data](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/552/analysing-this-sites-traffic#comment1665_552).

Comment: Apparently, we're all the rage for poor male asian grad students! XD